# How to get blank images from imageGetter

Tags: android

i want to get text as spanned in order to have the html view of the text.
But,i dont want to get images.Is that possible?

This is my code:

```
       Spanned description2=Html.fromHtml(des.get(position),null,null);
  TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.descr);
            text.setText(description2);
```

but it returns me some green boxes for the photos that i dont want!PLease help

WITH IMAGES:

String description2 = des.get(position).toString();

```
  Spanned description = Html.fromHtml(description2, new ImageGetter() {
            @Override
         public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {                  
            Drawable d = null;
            try {
                        InputStream src = imageFetch(source);
                        d = Drawable.createFromStream(src, "src");
                        if(d != null){
        d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),
        d.getIntrinsicHeight());

                        }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();  
            }

        return d;
        }

            public InputStream imageFetch(String source)
                    throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(source);
        Object o = url.getContent();
        InputStream content = (InputStream)o;
        // add delay here (see comment at the end)     
        return content;
        }

        },null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must override the `ImageGetter`'s `getDrawable` implementation, since the default implementation returns those ugly green squares:

```
private class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter
{
   @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source)
    {
      return new BitmapDrawable();
    }
};
```

and then switch your current code to:

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter();
 Spanned description2=Html.fromHtml(des.get(position),imageGetter,null);
  TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.descr);
            text.setText(description2);
```

now, regarding to what you asked in the comments, you have to offload the actual download from your UIthread, try using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864931/cannot-touch-view-from-another-thread-how-to-make-it-possible/8865148#8865148) (take a look at my answer, this is the way to use Threads with Handlers) and if still unclear, just ask again.

Comment: Thanks mate,that works!But,if i want to get images,there is a big delay until the images load..Is there any way to fix it?Generaly,is that a good idea to use spanned to get images and text from the rss?

Comment: i m asking because with that way,the green squares disappear(as we wanted) but the space that the had is still remaining..

Comment: If you want to get the images then you must override the ImageGetter differently, you can start a thread that will download all images and present them on screen when it's down downloading using a handler or an AsyncTask.

Comment: Would you like to create a new question for this in order to answer it with more details?

Comment: I am not sure I'm following, do you want the images or not?

Comment: You should put all your downloading in a thread, doing it on the UI will make it unresponsive.